# No me reconoce los endpoints en spring con mysql local

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Veréis estoy intentando hacer que mi microservicio de spring se conecte a una base de datos local. La cuestión es que se conecta pero los endpoints que pongo es como que no funciona.

Ahora mismo mi código está así:

**Manager:**

```
@Service
public class PerfilManager {

@Autowired
private PerfilRepository repository;

protected PerfilRepository getRepository() {
    return repository;
}

public List<PerfilEntity> getListaPerfiles(){
    return repository.findAll();
}}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface PerfilRepository extends JpaRepository<PerfilEntity, Long> {}
```

**Entity:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "perfil")
public class PerfilEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String nombre;

private String shortcut; }
```

**DTO:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class PerfilDTO {
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;

    private String shortcut;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public interface PerfilController {

    @FeignClient(FeignVariables.MICROSERVICE_ID)
    interface feign extends PerfilController {
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/listPerfiles")
    ResponseEntity<List<PerfilDTO>> listPerfiles();

}
```

**CONTROLLER IMPL**

```
@RestController
public class PerfilControllerImpl implements PerfilController {

    @Autowired
    private PerfilManager manager;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<PerfilDTO>> listPerfiles() {
        List<PerfilEntity> entityList = manager.getListaPerfiles();
        List<PerfilDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<PerfilDTO>();

        if(entityList.size() != 0) {
            for(PerfilEntity perfil : entityList) {
                PerfilDTO pDTO = new PerfilDTO();
                pDTO.setId(perfil.getId());
                pDTO.setNombre(perfil.getNombre());
                pDTO.setShortcut(perfil.getShortcut());
                dtoList.add(pDTO);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<List<PerfilDTO>>(dtoList, HttpStatus.OK); 


        }   else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<PerfilDTO>>(dtoList, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

    }

}
```

Vale. Esto es un ejemplo de todo mi codigo.

Como veis hago lo basico. El Feign Variables no lo pongo porque es solo una clase que devuelve el nombre del micro.

Ahora pongo lo de mi .properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yufit
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

## Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Lo dicho, se me conecta a la base de datos pero no recibo nada a cambio cuando pongo:

**localhost:8080/perfil/listPerfiles**

No se cual podria ser el error...

Este es lo que devuelve en consola:

```
    2019-07-24 17:32:48.913  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-07-24 17:32:49.107  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$649d9ac1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-07-24 17:32:50.595  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.d.ms.yufit.Yufit.YufitApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-07-24 17:32:51.844  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-07-24 17:32:51.969  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 44ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-07-24 17:32:52.239  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=f663ecc1-3d85-3053-91c9-573eda8f067a
2019-07-24 17:32:52.409  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$488397c4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-07-24 17:32:52.438  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$649d9ac1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-07-24 17:32:52.939  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-07-24 17:32:53.000  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-07-24 17:32:53.001  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-07-24 17:32:53.213  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-07-24 17:32:53.213  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2609 ms
2019-07-24 17:32:53.728  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-07-24 17:32:54.174  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-07-24 17:32:54.416  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-07-24 17:32:54.513  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-07-24 17:32:54.515  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-07-24 17:32:54.813  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-07-24 17:32:55.290  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-07-24 17:32:55.595  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-07-24 17:32:55.613  WARN 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.a.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration      : No spring.application.name found, defaulting to 'application'
2019-07-24 17:32:55.616  WARN 7008 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-07-24 17:32:55.616  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-07-24 17:32:55.629  WARN 7008 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-07-24 17:32:55.629  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-07-24 17:32:55.988  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-07-24 17:32:56.060  WARN 7008 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-07-24 17:32:56.373  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-07-24 17:32:57.749  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2019-07-24 17:32:58.024  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-07-24 17:32:58.026  INFO 7008 --- [  restartedMain] o.d.ms.yufit.Yufit.YufitApplication      : Started YufitApplication in 10.728 seconds (JVM running for 14.23)
```

Saludos y espero que me ayudeis!

Comment: Con *endpoints que pongo*, ¿te refieres a que pones la URL en un navegador y obtienes un 404?

Comment: Exacto @PabloLozano me sale un 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que tu error esta en la definición de tus clases, ya que spring reconoce como "endPointRest", los métodos que están bajo la etiqueta restController, por ende creo que esta demás hacer interface a perfil controller;

debería quedar algo asi.

```
@RestController
public class PerfilController {

        @FeignClient(FeignVariables.MICROSERVICE_ID)
        interface feign extends PerfilController {
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/listPerfiles")
        ResponseEntity<List<PerfilDTO>> listPerfiles();

}
```

la lógica de esta clase, por orden deberías crear otra clase de tipo service 
algo así PerfilService, si quieres a esta clase le puedes hacer con interfaz lo cual también creo que esta demás,

saludos

Comment: He seguido tu consejo poniendo la logica en el controller y declarandolo como RestController, me sigue saliendo el 404.

Comment: Hola si quieres me envías tu proyecto y lo reviso pfernandeza@gmail.com

Comment: Ahora voy, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot por defecto está configurado para generar un JAR en lugar de un WAR (la aplicación no necesita un contenedor para ser desplegada), y por tanto generalmente (a menos que lo configures así) no necesitas poner el nombre de la aplicación en la URL, debería bastarte con

```
http://localhost:8080/listPerfiles
```

Comment: He probado, y me sigue saliendo un 404.. no cojo el porque, he echo miles de veces la verdad, y nada. Esta vez no sale.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que hay un error en la ruta del endpoint, deberia ser

`http://localhost:8080/listPerfiles`

en lugar de

`http://localhost:8080/perfil/listPerfiles`

Comment: Buenas @Andres Sandoval, al poner esa url, me sigue saliendo un 404, osea, me sigue sin reconocer